# FragmentからActivityに遷移したい

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Android Studioに初めから入っている、Bottom navigationを使ってプログラミングしているんですが、FragmentからActivityへの画面遷移の方法がわかりません。

以下のようにコーディングしたところ、runするとエラーは出ないのですが、このFragmentに遷移した瞬間（DashboardFragmentに移った瞬間です）エミュレーター上でアプリが落ちてしまいます。なにか解決策はありますでしょうか？？

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dashboardViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transaction, container, false)

        val layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, null)
        val image: ImageView = layout.findViewById<View>(R.id.image) as ImageView

        val button = layout.findViewById<Button>(R.id.start)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(activity,ChatActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        return root
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問のタイトルには概要を書き出してみてください。タグ以上の情報が無いです。

Answer (score 1):

具体的なエラーが示されていないのでなんともいえませんが、エラーが発生する前の行で、

```
val image: ImageView = layout.findViewById<View>(R.id.image) as ImageView
```

という呼び出しがなされています。これが動いているのであれば、エラーが発生した行についても、

```
val button = layout.findViewById<Button>(R.id.start)
```

とすると動作するかもしれません（`layout.`を追加して、`View`のメソッドを呼び出すことを示しています）。[リファレンス](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int))を見ると、`findViewById`は`View`と`Activity`の両方に定義されていることがわかります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたところを修正して、投稿を編集しました。これでやるとエラーは出ないのですが、アプリがクラッシュしてしまいます。助けてほしいです。

Comment: 「クラッシュします」だけでは見当がつきませんね。スタックトレースなどを見せていただけますか？(質問を編集してください)